# Meaning of "Elin"

Tags: etymology, names, sanskrit

Elin is supposed to mean "Woman of Intelligence" in Sanskrit see http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Elin. However, I was not able to verify this independently in Sanskrit dictionaries on the web or on google books.

Also does it make a difference if it is spelled Elin or Elyn?

This might be off-topic but I would appreciate it if somebody could take the time to answer the question.

Comment: Hi and welcome. That's fine, etymology is on topic.

Comment: As a general rule, ignore all of the online baby name etymology sites, especially when it comes to etymologies. They simply amass urban legends and never do the research. In this case it is (AFAIK) a Scandinavian version of Greek Helena.

Comment: thinkbabynames.com is not a realiable source of name etymologies. In fact, there very few babyname websites with good etymologies. You may want to consult http://behindthename.com or http://www.babynames.ch

Answer (score 2):

The word "elin" exists neither in Hindi nor in Sanskrit as anything remotely close to the meaning you found on the web. The only possibility for this word to exist in Skt. is as a derivation from Skt. *ela*, then meaning "possessing *ela*". *Ela*, though, does not have too much meaning, see here (type "ela" in Harvard-Kyoto input):

http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/monier/

Moreover, *elin* then is a masculine. Precisely there is no word similar to *elin* in Sanskrit, which could possibly be feminine.